# Allow user to edit content editor webpart on specific pages

Tags: 2013, permissions, content-editor-web-part

We have a couple of web part pages in our publishing site that we want different users to be able to change the text inside a content editor webpart. The user has permission to edit the page and can get into edit mode. They can see the content editor webpart and make changes to its settings, but can't get into the actual content.

When selecting the content the ribbon doesn't change and have the rich editor controls, nor can they view the source. That is what I mean by "doesn't allow them to edit."

Found [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25528/contenteditor-webpart-edit-permissions) Which talks about giving Add/Customize Pages permissions. I did give the user **Design** (which includes the Add/Customize permission) and even **Full Control** on the page, but nothing changed.

We **don't want to give the user full control of the site** or **even full control of the Pages library**. Just specific pages.

Is it possible to give a user permission to change the content on just specific pages?

Comment: Have you created a group for users who can edit content editor web part ?

Comment: And what group would that be and where would I asign that? I've given both design permissions and full control to both the individual page and the pages library. I don't want to give either of those things to this user for the entire site.

Answer (score 4):

Solution is explained here: [ContentEditor WebPart Edit Permissions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25528/contenteditor-webpart-edit-permissions)

Permission "*Add and Customize Pages  -  Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible editor.*" must be granted at site level. If you grant this permission only at page level, it won't work. So:

1. Go to site settings > Site permissions
2. Click on "Permission Levels" and add a new permission level, for example "Edit web parts". In the permissions, click on permission "*Add and Customize Pages  -  Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible editor.*"
3. Save
4. Go to your web part page and edit its permissions. Grant permissions "Contribute - ..." (and "Approve - ... " if needed) to the appropriate user of SharePoint group

Now your users or group is able to edit Content Editor web part's content.

Pierre

Answer (score 1):

This is just an option. Check whether the Content editor webpart is placed inside the div for which `contenteditable` attribute is set to `false`. In that case make it true.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
----------
</div>
```

Comment: I'm the site collection owner and can edit the webpart. When I check from my account it does show true. The user I'm trying to give access to isn't in the office today so I don't know what it would say for her. But the content editor is in the right spot for someone with the correct permissions to edit. It is amazing to me that there isn't a clear easy answer to this.